# Highcharts increase the space/gap between grouped data series

Tags: highcharts, space, between, series

I want to group the data series so that they are separated from each other. My chart at the moment looks like (s26.postimg.org/ew08ku2mh/org.jpg) but it should be like (http://s26.postimg.org/hd6xuzg7d/new.jpg)

Please look at the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h332ubtj/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing your data setup.

Try :

```
plotOptions: {
    "series":{  "pointPadding":0,
                "groupPadding":0.1,
                "pointWidth":25,
                "dataLabels":{ "enabled":true,
                               "style":{"color":"black","fontSize":"12"},
                                "format":"{point.y:.1f}"
                }
    }
}
```